# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DateTimeField' and 'DateTimeField'

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime

I have the following equation in a Django 2.1 class:

```
import datetime
class FormBacktest(forms.Form):
     dateStart= forms.DateTimeField(label="Date Start", widget=DateTimePickerInput()
    dateEnd= forms.DateTimeField(label="Date End", widget=DateTimePickerInput()
    timeInMin = int((dateEnd-dateStart).total_seconds()/60)
```

I know from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) that the DateTimeField is a  datetime.datetime instance, so [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156031/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-time-and-datetime-time) should be overcomed.

Any recommendations?

Comment: Define a property for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `DateTimeField` is a form field, not a `datetime` instance. However when you take input from that field, you will get a `datetime` object. you can access its value from `cleaned_data`, for example like this:

```
# in view

def someview(request):
   form = FormBacktest(request.POST or None)
   if request.method == "POST": # its a post request
       if form.is_valid():
           date_start = form.cleaned_data.get('dateStart')
           date_end = form.cleaned_data.get('dateEnd')
           difference= date_end - date_start  # time delta object
```

Please check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#field-data) on more details on how to get data from form. Also, please remove `timeInMin` from form.

Comment: That is it! it must be implemented from the cleaned_data!

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you're trying to accomplish but I'll try to help.It seems like you're mixing up forms and model instances.

If you want to show `timeInMin` on the form then you'll need to make it an Integer field (probably small will do) and then use javascript to do the math and update the field when a user enters the start and end date.

IF you want to set `timeInMin` on submit in the database for the model instance, and you don't care about updating the value with Javascript on the form when it's updated, then you'll just do it in your form handler view, or even by overriding the model's save method.

With what you have now, the `DateEnd` isn't instantiated when you're trying to reference it, and `DateEnd` isn't a value anyway, it's a form field.