# How to take difference of 2 time rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel('/content/Haoling peak time data (1).xlsx')
df['Difference'] = df['ORDER END TIME']-df['ORDER START TIME']
```

error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156031/typeerror-unsupported-operand-types-for-datetime-time-and-datetime-time)

Comment: please post df.dtypes

Comment: `datetime.time`, e.g., `'22:17:10'` doesn't support subtraction. `datetime.datetime` does. Seems like your values are just clocktime without a date. Are these meant to be always within the same day?

Comment: @gtomer ARRIVAL TIME                  object
ORDER START TIME              object
ORDER END TIME                object
TYPE(MACHINE OR STAFF)        object
COLLECT TIME                  object
TYPE(TAKE AWAY OR EAT-IN)     object
Unnamed: 6                   float64
ARRIVAL                      float64
COLLET                       float64
Unnamed: 9                    object
dtype: object

Comment: @MYousefi yes i just need to take the diff of the time to run an analysis so the date doesnt matter, is there any way i could just take the time difference??

Answer (score 0):

Times have to be converted to date times in order to work. You can do it with something like this.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

def daytime(time):
    return datetime.combine(date.min, time)

df['Difference'] = df['ORDER END TIME'].apply(daytime) - df['ORDER START TIME'].apply(daytime)
```

```
  ORDER START TIME ORDER END TIME        Difference
0         09:00:00       09:01:00   0 days 00:01:00
1         10:00:00       09:59:00 -1 days +23:59:00
```

Assuming everything is within a 24-hour period, if start time is after end time we'd have a negative difference. If we need to fix this we can use modulo.

```
day = timedelta(days=1)
df['Difference'] = df['Difference'] % day
```

```
  ORDER START TIME ORDER END TIME      Difference
0         09:00:00       09:01:00 0 days 00:01:00
1         10:00:00       09:59:00 0 days 23:59:00
```